# Selecting 3 identical items from list

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find if there are 3 identical items in list.

It should compare elements using **overridden `.Equals()` method**. I've tried many ways and failed.
It doesn't matter if it returns bool value or items itself.
The function will be called every time after new item is added, so it does not matter how as long as it detects the point when 3 same items are in list.

This is probably something trivial, but my knowledge of Linq is very weak.

Comment: @JakubKonecki `homework` tag is deprecated: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/147423

Comment: It is not a homework. I'm finishing my ASP.NET chess, plan was to use linq to detect threefold repetition. I could to it the regular way, but I like things linq can do, so I'm trying to implement it whenever I can and learn it in the way.

Comment: Do you need to find exactly 3, or 'at least' 3? From your question it's not totally clear. In the first case you cannot stop processing the whole list when you found 3, only in the second. If it's 'at least', then the selected answer has a bug.

Comment: I've tried some crazy things. First I wanted to select all Distinct elements and look if count of them less by 2 from count of original elements. That ofc would not work since if there are only 2 identical items, I would get count difference of 1 and thats now what I need. After that I tried to select all non-distinct items and then select non-distinct items again. If count of remaining items would have been more then 1, then we have a winner. At that point I knew that I'm taking the "wrong" approach, and that there must be easier solution.

Comment: @Wasp After every chess move is made, a "screenshot" of that Board is added to my History. After every move i go trough that history and search for 3 identical items. When I find them, I offer Draw to player. So technically I need 3. When I find them, that's it.
If i need more that 3, i will put ">" instead of "==" in solution. ;)

Comment: So technically you need 'at least' three, which allows some optimization, and I guess the selected answer might need a fix :) If performance is really an issue, I think you should need some extension method that enumerates the elements and does some buffering, you could find an answer with at most one iteration. IMHO the approach from Tim is good too if the performance is important but not the hardest constraint (it works also in the case 'at least 3').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
return
    collection.Any(any => collection.Count(item => item.Equals(any)) == 3);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Only thing I'm interested now is: Does it stops searching after it finds first occurrence?

Comment: If you have 100 elements in your list, and only the last 3 are equal to each other, you will fully enumerate the list 98 times + one enumeration that stops at the 98th element

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic: `Any` stops as soon as the predicate matches. In this case when the subquery counts 3 duplicates. The only problem in this approach is that it needs to count the **total-count**.

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic: Is it correct that you need to know that the exact count is 3 instead minimum three?

Comment: @TimSchmelter 
1st post: I think I'm failing to understand the problem? I'm still trying to understand your solution. :/
2nd post: Well, it will be detected on 3 for sure, so yes. I'll edit question.

Comment: Consider that 10,000,000 items are in the list and the first 9,000,000 items are different. This approach would need to look into all of these and count their occurences (9,000,000 * 10,000,000 comparisons). Then consider that the last million items are duplicates. This would compare all 1,000,000 with the other 10,000,000 items even if it would know after three items that a minimum of three duplicates exists. That's where my approach comes into play. It just checks if **one** given item exists at least n-times in the sequence, then it stops and returns true.

Comment: @Tim but it's still true that for the first 9,000,000 elements you'd enumerate the whole list each time, right? Check my answer, that would enumerate the whole list just once (with memory cost, true, the problem should be sized in terms of memory/speed before deciding).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for explanation. My List will not be long (200 elements at most in rare occasions). I will try to get how you and Wasps' solutions work for better understanding of linq.

Comment: @DusanVasiljevic: Btw, i've compared this with [my approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12530530/284240) with 10,000,000 random integers. My took 6.7 milliseconds. I've cancelled the measurement of Jan's after more than 8 hours ;-)

Comment: [Here](http://ideone.com/WmUzv)`s the code if anyone wants to test it himself. Note that it will not work on ideone(runtime error, i assume because it takes too long)

Answer (score 1):

By grouping items by itself and evaluating if any group contains exactly three items, you will receive expected result.

```
private bool ContainsTriple<T>(IList<T> items){
    return items.GroupBy(i => i).Any(l => l.Count() == 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To express better my concept:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FirstRepeatedTimes<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int threshold)
    {
        if (!sequence.Any())
            throw new ArgumentException("Sequence must contain elements", "sequence");
        if (threshold < 2)
            throw new ArgumentException("DuplicateCount must be greater than 1", "threshold");

        return FirstRepeatedTimesImpl(sequence, threshold);
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> FirstRepeatedTimesImpl<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, int threshold)
    {
        var map = new Dictionary<T, int>();
        foreach(var e in sequence)
        {
            if (!map.ContainsKey(e))
                map.Add(e, 0);
            if (map[e] + 1 == threshold)
            {
                yield return e;
                yield break;
            }
            map[e] = map[e] + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

you would use it like this:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1,2,2,3,4,3,3 };

// list contains anything for 3 times?
var found = list.FirstRepeatedTimes(3).Any();
```

It could potentially consume some more memory, but it enumerates the list at most once. Is this Linq? The way I wrote it, it yields exactly 1 element (the first found), or no element, and you can further compose on top of it if you want. You could use `FirstOfDefault()` instead of `Any()`, and have then the found element or `0` (or `null` if we deal with reference types). This way you have the choice.

It's just another way to see it.

Comment: +1: nice alternative for very large sequences or even more when there are a lot of duplicates and `threshold` is quite large.

Comment: Btw, [here's](http://ideone.com/3m1L4) a measurement. Your approach is a little bit faster with 10,000,000 items ;)

Comment: Interesting :)  But the buffering approach (mine) gives its best when the repetitions are at the end of the list. Try to modify your list generation like this:    `for (int i = 0; i < 9000; i++)
   {
    list.Add(i);
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
   {
    list.Add(9000 + r.Next(1, 10));
   }` and you will see that, even with a much much smaller list (10,000 elements, with no repetitions in the first 9,000 elements) the buffering approach is about 1,000 times faster... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> col = new List<string>();

        col.Add("a");
        Console.WriteLine(Has_3(col));
        Console.ReadKey();
        col.Add("a");
        Console.WriteLine(Has_3(col));
        Console.ReadKey();
        col.Add("a");
        Console.WriteLine(Has_3(col));
        Console.ReadKey(); 
        col.Add("a");
        Console.WriteLine(Has_3(col));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static bool Has_3(List<string> col)
    {
        return col.Count(x => x == "a").Equals(3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that this could probably be done by using the Group() method, something like this:

```
var ints = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 2 });

var first = ints.GroupBy(n => n)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .First(g => g.Count >= 3);

Console.WriteLine("Found {0} instances of {1}", first.Count, first.Key);
```

This snippet checks for 3 or more of the same item, and selects the first item that meets the criteria, you might want to change this. And adapt it to your specific objects instead of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension:

```
public static bool ContainsNTimes<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T element, int duplicateCount)
{
    if (element == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("element");
    if (!sequence.Any())
        throw new ArgumentException("Sequence must contain elements", "sequence");
    if (duplicateCount < 1)
         throw new ArgumentException("DuplicateCount must be greater 0", "duplicateCount");

    bool containsNTimes = sequence.Where(i => i.Equals(element))
                            .Take(duplicateCount)
                            .Count() == duplicateCount;
    return containsNTimes;
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1,2,2,3,4,3,3 };

// list contains 2 for 3 times?
bool contains2ThreeTimes = list.ContainsNTimes(2, 3);

// any element in the list iscontained 3 times (or more)?
bool anyContains3Times = list.Any(i => list.ContainsNTimes(i, 3));

Console.WriteLine("List contains 2 for 3 times? " + contains2ThreeTimes); // false
Console.WriteLine("Any element in the list is contained 3 times (or more)? " + anyContains3Times); // true (3)
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/Ozk9v

Should be quite efficient since it uses deferred execution. It enumerates the sequences until n-items were found.